# How can I take repeating rows and transform the data frame to add columns of unique identifiers in R?

Tags: r

I have a very large data frame. In simple form it would look like this...

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 20, ncol = 2))
df[1:10,1] <- c("HeaderStart","LevelName","Experiment","SessionTime",
              "Subject","Session","ImgPath","RandomSeed",
              "DisplayRefreshRate","Level")

df[11:20,1] <- c("HeaderStart","LevelName","Experiment","SessionTime",
               "Subject","Session","ImgPath","RandomSeed",
               "DisplayRefreshRate","Level")

df[1:10,2] <- seq(1,10,1)
df[11:20,2] <- seq(1,10,1)

           

                   X1 X2
1         HeaderStart  1
2           LevelName  2
3          Experiment  3
4         SessionTime  4
5             Subject  5
6             Session  6
7             ImgPath  7
8          RandomSeed  8
9  DisplayRefreshRate  9
10              Level 10
11        HeaderStart  1
12          LevelName  2
13         Experiment  3
14        SessionTime  4
15            Subject  5
16            Session  6
17            ImgPath  7
18         RandomSeed  8
19 DisplayRefreshRate  9
20              Level 10
```

I would want to change it to this...

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 3))

df[1:10,1] <- c("HeaderStart","LevelName","Experiment","SessionTime",
                "Subject","Session","ImgPath","RandomSeed",
                "DisplayRefreshRate","Level")

df[1:10,2] <- seq(1,10,1)
df[1:10,3] <- seq(1,10,1)

                   X1 X2 X3
1         HeaderStart  1  1
2           LevelName  2  2
3          Experiment  3  3
4         SessionTime  4  4
5             Subject  5  5
6             Session  6  6
7             ImgPath  7  7
8          RandomSeed  8  8
9  DisplayRefreshRate  9  9
10              Level 10 10
```

Essentially, I would have the unique column names in one column and add columns with the respected value or character associated in the row but in a new column.

Edit: Note that this is a simple format. I can't just simply take 10 rows and throw them into a new column and delete the final rows. And the order of the names is always changing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dcast` combined with `rowid`:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)

dcast(df, X1 ~ rowid(X1), value.var = "X2") |>
  rename_with(~ paste0("X", seq_along(.))) |>
  arrange(X2)

                   X1 X2 X3
1         HeaderStart  1  1
2           LevelName  2  2
3          Experiment  3  3
4         SessionTime  4  4
5             Subject  5  5
6             Session  6  6
7             ImgPath  7  7
8          RandomSeed  8  8
9  DisplayRefreshRate  9  9
10              Level 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option  - create a sequence column by 'X2' and reshape to wide with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
 mutate(rn = rowid(X1, X2)+1) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = X2, names_prefix = "X")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   X1                    X2    X3
   <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>
 1 HeaderStart            1     1
 2 LevelName              2     2
 3 Experiment             3     3
 4 SessionTime            4     4
 5 Subject                5     5
 6 Session                6     6
 7 ImgPath                7     7
 8 RandomSeed             8     8
 9 DisplayRefreshRate     9     9
10 Level                 10    10
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), X1 ~ paste0("X", rowid(X1, X2) + 1))[order(X2)]
```

-output

```
                     X1 X2 X3
 1:        HeaderStart  1  1
 2:          LevelName  2  2
 3:         Experiment  3  3
 4:        SessionTime  4  4
 5:            Subject  5  5
 6:            Session  6  6
 7:            ImgPath  7  7
 8:         RandomSeed  8  8
 9: DisplayRefreshRate  9  9
10:              Level 10 10
```

Comment: the mutate function ended up concatenating certain rows in a column for me and the dcast made everything into a 1 or 0 and got rid of characters

Comment: The image I added is a good portion of the csv file I am working with to provide a better example

Comment: @jc2525 can you use `dput` i.e. `dput(head(yourdata, 30))` and get the output of that with your expected output.  This will give the structure correctly i.e. the column class and other stuff

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data, a base R solution might be:

```
classes = table(df[, 1])
results = t(sapply(names(classes), function(x){
    df[which(df[, 1] == x), 2]
}))
```

This will fail though if there are not always the same group of unique classnames repeating each time (if that is the case, then it is hard to see a solution that would reliably return a matrix-like result).

If each of the groups of classnames comes from a separate input document, then it would be much easier to come up with a robust solution.